# Save a system property on program exit

Tags: c#, wpf

been looking through and can't really find anything that will relate fully to what I'm trying to do here. I've created a system property in the WPF application called 'firstrun', which is a bool. Trying to get the program to read if it's true, and then act differently on the first time running the program. But then once closed, it sets it to false. My code is like this and it's still true each time I run the program:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    bool firstRun = Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (firstRun)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("First run");
        }
        else
        {
            // Run rest of program
            MessageBox.Show("This is not the first run");
        }
    }

    private void windowClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        this.firstRun = false;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: How is `windowClosing` referenced? Are you sure you register the event handler?

Comment: You change value in MainWindow member (bool firstRun). You need to change property value in settings (Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun) and then call Settings.Default.Save(); ...

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/151Q0O2H3R1l/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-03%20at%2001.47.52%20LATE.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you change value in MainWindow member:

```
bool firstRun = Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun;
```

You need to change property value in settings (Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun) and then call Settings.Default.Save() like this:

```
private void windowClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun = false;
   Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

For this functionality you have to change scope in settings file from Application to User value. In user scope property has getter and setter

Comment: The easy message is: don't assign variables for things like this to prevent messing things up.

Comment: In your Settings file you have to change scope from Application to User and then property is not readonly :-)

Comment: @PatrickHofman: when you have scope set to Application VS generate only getter in property, but in User scope generate getter and setter... try it... But maybe i am wrong - i have not installed VS on this computer